# How to obtain route polyline from REST API

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, here-api

I am developing an App using Shiny and leaflet in R. And I need to plot the route obtain with REST API.

I try to obtain Polylines using this:

```
query <- paste0("&waypoint0=geo!", 
              lat_usuario, 
              ",", 
              long_usuario, 
              "&waypoint1=geo!",
              lat_of, 
              ",", 
              long_of, 
              "&departure=", fecha, 
              "&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled")

paste0("https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json", 
     "?app_id=", App_id, "&app_code=", App_code, query) %>%
RCurl::getURL(verbose = FALSE) %>%
RJSONIO::fromJSON() %>%
.[["response"]] %>%
.[["route"]] %>%
.[[1]] %>%
.[["leg"]] %>%
.[[1]] %>%
.[["maneuver"]] %>%
sapply("[[", "position") %>%
return()
```

But, when I represent using this code:

```
leafletProxy("mapa", data = values$tabla) %>%
   clearShapes()  %>%
   addPolylines(pol[2,], pol[1,], stroke=0.2)
```

I obtain that polylines aren't inside the street. As shown in image:

[image: i]

How can I do to plot route inside the streets?

Comment: Please clarify if the question is regarding the Here API or the tool/language you are using. If it is about the language then we suggest you to add the related language in your tag so that language experts can help you.

Comment: The question is about HERE API. I don't know how adquire route layout to plot in map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself.

The key is include "&routeAttributes=sh" in the query. And, then, we recieve the shapes of route (to be able to plot them).